Meaning of notation $\beta(ij)$ in Lemma 27.2.14 for exponents in monomial orders
The following are partly taken from Malik and Sen's Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra
Background
Lemma 27.2.14:  Let $I$ be a momomial ideal and $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]$.
Then the following are equivalent
$(i)$ $f\in I$.
$(ii)$ Every term of $f$ lies in $I$.
$(iii)$ $f=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{t} a_\alpha x^{\alpha}$ for some $a_\alpha \in K$ and $x^\alpha\in I, 0\leq \alpha \leq t$.

Proof: That $(iii)\Rightarrow (ii)\Rightarrow(i)$ is immediate.
$(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$    Since $f\in I, f=\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ for some $h_i\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\alpha(i)\in A$, where $I=\langle\{x^\alpha\mid\alpha \in A\}\rangle$.  Now $h_i=\sum_{j=0}^{n_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}, i=1,\ldots,q, k_{ij}\in K,$ for all $i,j$. Thus,
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=q}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$$
Therefore, $(iii)$ holds since $x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$ is a monomial in $I$.

Here is a screenshot of Lemma 2 (Lemma 27.2.14 in the screenshot),

Questions
I have some questions about notations for denoting exponents for monomials.
For the proof of Lemma 27.2.14 above where it has $I=\{x^\alpha\mid\alpha \in A\}$, but then shortly after I see $\sum_{j=0}^{n_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=q}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$, What is the meaning of the notation: $\beta(ij)$ mean. Also how do $j$ relate to $i$?
Thank you in advance

Since $I = (x^\alpha \mid \alpha \in A)$ is a monomial ideal and $ f \in I $, then there exists some polynomials $ p_1(x), \dots, p_m(x) \in K[x_1, \dots, x_n] $, and some $ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m \in A $, such that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} p_i(x) x^{\alpha_i}.
$$
Since $ p_i(x) \in K[x_1, \dots, x_n] $, we may expend it as follows:
$$
p_i(x) = \sum_{|\beta| = 0}^{d_i} c_{i, \beta} x^{\beta}.
$$
Thus
$$
f(x) 
= 
\sum_{i = 1}^{m} 
\left( \sum_{|\beta| = 0}^{d_i} c_{i, \beta} x^{\beta} \right) x^{\alpha_i}.
$$
The $x^\beta$ here is what $x^{\beta(ij)}$ is in the book. That is to say, the "$j$ " in $\beta(ij)$ is just a notation for summation, one can use that notation "$\beta$ " to sum the momomials so that "$j$ " can be omitted completely.

does $|\beta|$ denote the norm of $\beta$?  So if $\beta=(2,3,1)$ then $|\beta|=1+2+3$?

Yes, since $x^{\beta}$ means $ x_1^{\beta_1} \cdots x_n^{\beta_n} $. @Seth

but then $|\beta|$ doesn't necessarily have to start at $1$?  Because the biggest $\beta_i$ could start at $2$ or greater?,

I'm sorry. It is a typo. It should start from $0$. @Seth

ah kk.  thank you for your answer.  :)

You are welcome~ @Seth
